# class member not initializing

Tags: c++, initialization-list

I have the following piece of code and the simple if statement: `if (voxels_)` where voxels_  should be NULL is failing.  The code:

```
template<class T, typename REAL = float>
class NDIMVoxelStructure
{
public:
    inline NDIMVoxelStructure (): voxels_(NULL){}
    inline virtual ~NDIMVoxelStructure (){ this->clear();}

    /////////////////ERROR occurs at if(voxels_) //////////////////
    inline void 
    clear (){if ( voxels_ ){delete[] voxels_; voxels_ = NULL;}} 


    inline void
    build (const std::vector<REAL> bounds, std::vector<int> num_of_voxels) {
        this->clear();
        // more code
    }

protected:
    T* voxels_;
};

Class ModelLibrary {

    ModelLibrary () {
        hash_table_.build (bounds_vector, num_of_cells_vector);
    }

    struct Quad{
            const ORROctree::Node::Data* first;
            const ORROctree::Node::Data* second;
            const float* f1;
            const float* f2;
    };

    typedef std::list<Quad > quad_list;
    // these two types hide base class types
    typedef std::map<const Model*, quad_list> HashTableCell; 
    typedef NDIMVoxelStructure<HashTableCell, float> HashTable;

protected:
    HashTable hash_table;
};

int main() {
    ModelLibrary library; 
}
```

I get a segfault in the clear() method.  Using gdb I got the address of `voxels_` is set to `0xa` which is strange.  I am initializing it to NULL so `if (voxels_)` should simply return false.  Any Ideas would be helpful.  This is driving me crazy

Comment: You are trying to access an aleady-deleted `NDIMVoxelStructure` object, probably in some code you have not shown.

Comment: Read this: [C++: The Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming))

Comment: This question needs a minimum viable example to be answered.  Did your example compile and produce an error?

Comment: What are you doing with `voxels_` in method `build()` where it says: `// more code`?

Comment: @DarkFalcon I put a cout in my clear method before the "If" and it printed so NDIMVoxelStructure must exist.

Comment: @helb I tracted the error to the clear() method why would the rest of the code in build matter?

Comment: @Mustafa because the seg fault is only the symptom and not the cause of the error. I suspect you accidentally delete[] your voxels_ array twice or use `new` instead of `new[]` or do something crazy with your heap somewhere else, accidentally overwriting the voxels_ member. (These things _do_ happen in C++)...

Comment: @helb Actually the delete doesn't even get called because the program crashes at the `if voxels_`

Comment: This is the least of your problems, but you don't need the `if (voxels_)` - it is completely safe to `delete` a null pointer.

Comment: @Mustafa You wrote that voxels_ points to memory location 0xa. This is probably an invalid address for your application because in most cases, memory locations are aligned to 4 or 8 bytes (but this depends on so many things...). I suspect that you accidentally write to the memory where the voxels_ _pointer_ is stored. Do you use a statement like `*(&voxels_) = ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking into account that this is just a "miniature" version from real code. Can it be that your actual code is calling `NDIMVoxelStructure`'s copy constructor (e.g. through a function that returns a `NDIMVoxelStructure` element) and, then, `voxels_` is not properly initialized?

In previous situation, if `voxels_` is a pointer, default copy constructor would, initially, swallow copy the NULL value but, probably, something else can be running behind the scenes.

I would suggest to also define `NDIMVoxelStructure`'s copy constructor and check if it's called.